# how to add text and img in value button with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, button

I´m traying to create a dynamic button with jquery and API Redsys. But i want to change value for default to this button and i´m traying to do this:

```
$("#btn_submit").val('Pasarela de pago TPV - '+"<img src='{{ asset('media/santander.png') }}' name='logo' /> ");
```

and result it´s:

[image: result]

i want show this img in my button.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could like this:

```
e = "<img src='{{ asset('media/santander.png') }}' name='logo' />";
$("#btn_submit").html(`Pasarela de pago TPV - ${e}`);
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but not run your solution

Comment: my problem it´s that value for this button it´s "send" and this element not is a button it´s a input type submit

Comment: plase add html codes